# Custom WooCommerce Email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

After following [this article](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/#plugin), on how to add a custom WooCommerce email, we are having problems with sending the email.

We have custom order statuses:

```
wp-call-unconfirmed
wp-call-confirmed
```

And want to send an email to the admin when any order changes from **wp-call-unconfirmed** to **wp-call-confirmed**.

We have set up a plugin for the custom email with the following structure:

```
/woocommerce-call-confirmed
      /includes
          - class-wc-call-confirmed-email.php
      - woocommerce-call-confirmed-email.php
```

We have a function which changes the order status. We call the hook which triggers the email to be sent:

```
private function set_customer_call_verified( $order_id, $verified_status) 
{
    // Code ommitted, changes order status from unconfirmed->confirmed 

    // Is this the correct way to send our custom email?
    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_call_unconfirmed_to_call_confirmed_notification' );
}
```

Here are our email files:

> class-wc-call-confirmed-email.php

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * A custom Call Confirmed WooCommerce Email class
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @extends \WC_Email
 */
class WC_Call_Confirmed_Email extends WC_Email {
/**
     * Set email defaults
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function __construct() {

        // set ID, this simply needs to be a unique name
        $this->id = 'wc_call_confirmed';

        // this is the title in WooCommerce Email settings
        $this->title = 'Call Confirmed';

        // this is the description in WooCommerce email settings
        $this->description = 'Call Confirmed Notification emails are sent when a customer completes the Twilio API call';

        // these are the default heading and subject lines that can be overridden using the settings
        $this->heading = 'Call Confirmed';
        $this->subject = 'Call Confirmed';

        // these define the locations of the templates that this email should use, we'll just use the new order template since this email is similar
        $this->template_html  = 'emails/admin-new-order.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/admin-new-order.php';

        // Trigger on new paid orders
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_call_unconfirmed_to_call_confirmed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2  );

        // Call parent constructor to load any other defaults not explicity defined here
        parent::__construct();

        // this sets the recipient to the settings defined below in init_form_fields()
        $this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient' );

        // if none was entered, just use the WP admin email as a fallback
        if ( ! $this->recipient )
            $this->recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the email should actually be sent and setup email merge variables
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function trigger( $order_id ) {

        // bail if no order ID is present
        if ( ! $order_id )
            return;

        // setup order object
        $this->object = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        // replace variables in the subject/headings
        $this->find[] = '{order_date}';
        $this->replace[] = date_i18n( woocommerce_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );

        $this->find[] = '{order_number}';
        $this->replace[] = $this->object->get_order_number();

        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() )
            return;

        // woohoo, send the email!
        $this->send( 'example@email.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }

    /**
     * get_content_html function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * get_content_plain function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Settings Form Fields
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {

        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled'    => array(
                'title'   => 'Enable/Disable',
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => 'Enable this email notification',
                'default' => 'yes'
            ),
            'recipient'  => array(
                'title'       => 'Recipient(s)',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'Enter recipients (comma separated) for this email. Defaults to <code>%s</code>.', esc_attr( get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'subject'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Subject',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'This controls the email subject line. Leave blank to use the default subject: <code>%s</code>.', $this->subject ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'heading'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Email Heading',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'This controls the main heading contained within the email notification. Leave blank to use the default heading: <code>%s</code>.' ), $this->heading ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'email_type' => array(
                'title'       => 'Email type',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => 'Choose which format of email to send.',
                'default'     => 'html',
                'class'       => 'email_type',
                'options'     => array(
                    'plain'     => 'Plain text',
                    'html'      => 'HTML', 'woocommerce',
                    'multipart' => 'Multipart', 'woocommerce',
                )
            )
        );
    }

}
```

> woocommerce-call-confirmed-email.php

```
  <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Custom Call Confirmed Email
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 *  Add a custom email to the list of emails WooCommerce should load
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @param array $email_classes available email classes
 * @return array filtered available email classes
 */
function add_call_confirmed_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {

    // include our custom email class
    require( 'includes/class-wc-call-confirmed-email.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['WC_Call_Confirmed_Email'] = new WC_Call_Confirmed_Email();

    return $email_classes;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_call_confirmed_woocommerce_email' );
```

However, the email is not sent. I have searched the internet for a way to do this, and cannot find why it isn't working.

Is there anything we are missing that is preventing the email to be sent?